# how to break out of a loop listening on stdin?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdin

I have a while loop **in a separate thread** listening on `stdin`, waiting for text coming from another process. When my program is exiting, I would like to exit from this while loop and join the thread.

```
std::string line; 
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::stringstream linestream(line);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried closing `std::cin`?

Comment: If on posix compliant system, you might `select` or `poll` on `SDTIN_FILENO`.

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where [detaching](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) the thread could be appropriate. When the program exits the thread will be terminated.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks! that worked. I will mark this as answer if you repost it

Comment: @Aconcagua how do I close `std::cin` ?

Comment: Well, not exactly `std::cin`, but the file descriptor it accesses under the hoods: `close(STDIN_FILENO);` – which should provoke the active read failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the rare cases where [detaching](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) the thread could be appropriate. When the program exits the thread will be terminated.

```
std::thread thr(whatever);
thr.detach();
```